# dayjs - Calculate difference between hours and return it in minutes

Tags: javascript, dayjs

Given two time parameters like: "13:00" and "00:00"
How can I calculate the difference backwards and return it in minutes? My expected result is 780. Parameters can be 13:30. 13:45 etc.

API doc did not help, https://day.js.org/docs/en/display/difference, everybody is calculating date difference, not hours.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a library to do this.

You can split the strings by a colon, then use the [`Date` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date) to parse the hour and minutes. You can then subtract the two Dates to get the millisecond difference, and divide by 60000 to get the number of minutes:

```js
const a = "00:00";
const b = "13:00"



function calcDiff(start, end) {
  const [startHour, startMinutes] = start.split(":")
  const [endHour, endMinutes] = end.split(":")

  const diff = (new Date(null, null, null, endHour, endMinutes) - new Date(null, null, null, startHour, startMinutes)) / 60000
  return diff;
}

console.log(calcDiff(a, b))
```

Comment: Thank for your rapid answer. Your solution works like a charm, so I would accept as an answer. However if anyone else can feed my curiosity, I would appreciate the dayjs answer. Unfortunately the API Doc is not clear. Thanks again man, I was focusing on dayjs lol :)